# LLVM API Runtime Error using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, llvm

I've built LLVM 7.0.0 via CMake and Visual Studio 2017.
I copied code from [this tutorial](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl03.html).

It doesn't compile because of some warnings. However, I use pragma's like:
`#pragma warning(disable : 4146)` and it compiles fine. But when I run the program and typing invalid Kaleidoscope code to the terminal, LLVM API function `eraseFromParent` is called, which causes to this error:
[_CrtIsValidBlockPointer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RXVt.png)
What should I do? Is this a problem with LLVM support for Visual Studio 2017? Please help.

Comment: First of all: warnings are not to be ignored. The C4146 together with _CrtIsValidBlockPointer suggest that you've went outside of your memory boundary. There's a bug in your code. Or (less likely) in llvm. Anyway, show us [the minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we will look at it.

Comment: Ignored warning. Got broken code. News at 11.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I had to suppress warnings (C4146, C4996) because it's not my code, it's code from tutorial by LLVM devs. I don't think they would publish not-working code. What should I do then to build the minimal example of generating llvm-ir code? Problem appears inside library function, not mine.

Comment: Steps to reproduce problem: compile llvm 7.0 via CMake and VS2017, then copy&paste code from [link](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl03.html) into your project, then build (in any way, including suppressing warnings) and run it. Type something into the terminal that doesn't match Kaleidosope language grammar with semicolon at the end, for example: `abcd;`. Then function `eraseFromParent` will be called, which results into error. I'm sorry if that is not what you asked for, I could misunderstood you.

Comment: I finally found a solution described here: http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2016-February/095773.html. You need to disable /sdl flag in solution settings. It seems Visual Studio (unlike gcc on linux or clang on mac) do some extra checks and finds a code in LLVM's sources that leads to heap corruption.